# java interface constructor?

Tags: java, interface, constructor

i have a base class, a child class, an interface, and a child class that implements this interface

-base Abstract class Seq

```
public abstract class Seq {...some functions...}
```

-class For extends Seq

```
public class For extends Seq{
    int first, last, step;
    public For( int a, int b, int c)
      {...some work on a,b,c }
}
```

till now, everthing is perfectly fine! i tested it.

```
public interface SeqIt {
    public boolean function1();
    public int function2();
}
```

-class ForIt that implements SeqIt (the interface)
the problem is the child class constructor

```
public class ForIt implements SeqIt{
      public void ForIt( For x ) //here is the problem//
              {...the work i wanna do...}
          }
```

i have to call it from the main using this statement `ForIt fi = new ForIt(new For(3, 8, 2));`

so how should i write the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but it looks like your problem is that you have `void` in your constructor signature.

What you want is:

```
public ForIt( ... )
```

Comment: Daniel is right and than call it ForIt fi = new ForIt(new For(3, 8, 2)); , it will work

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want that `void` there -- you just want `public ForIt(For x)`.